# NoSuchAlgorithm for pkcs12 keystore key

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, pkcs#12

I am writing an example program to query a vendor's webservice from a java application. I am not doing this from a server, it is a java command-line desktop application. EDIT: using Java 7.

I have certificates provided by the vendor -- one includes a chain to identify the vendor, the other is a keystore to identify my company. I have imported the vendor certs into cacerts, and believe that to be working since it eliminated an error I used to get when creating the Service object.

I am getting a NoSuchAlgorithm error when I actually attempt to run the remote call to the webservice; does this mean that pkcs12 is not a valid type of keystore? Keystore Explorer can read this keystore, leading me to believe that using pkcs12 should be possible somehow.

So I want to know what I'm doing wrong, for instance, whether there is something I need to do for a PKCS12 type key. Since I specify a keystore with a VM command line option, I'm also puzzled why the SSL debug information does not list that keystore.

I run this with the following options:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl -Djavax.net.ssl.keystore="S:\Vendor Documentation\9.07\Web Services\MyCompanykickoff\VendorSaaSWebServices-Customer.pfx" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=cX5L9CTj -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12
```

And I get the following output:

```
run:
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EndorsingSupportingTokens" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice}CustomBinding_IWSTrust13Sync
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice}CustomBinding_IWSTrust13Sync1
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}TransportBinding" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Trust13" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Wss11" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl}UsingAddressing" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}TransportBinding" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Trust13" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Wss11" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0075: Policy assertion "{http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl}UsingAddressing" was evaluated as "UNKNOWN".
Dec 28, 2015 9:03:46 AM [com.sun.xml.internal.ws.policy.EffectiveAlternativeSelector]  selectAlternatives
WARNING: WSP0019: Suboptimal policy alternative selected on the client side with fitness "UNKNOWN".
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : pkcs12

keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
default context init failed: java.security.KeyStoreException: pkcs12
 not found
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:117)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:194)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:122)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:123)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:626)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:585)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:570)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:467)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:308)
all done
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.doInvoke(DispatchImpl.java:177)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.dispatch.DispatchImpl.invoke(DispatchImpl.java:203)
  at stsclientexample3.STSClientExample3.main(STSClientExample3.java:72)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:198)
  at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:205)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(HttpsClient.java:361)
  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:162)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:974)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:105)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
  at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1262)
  at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
  at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
  at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
  at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:97)
  at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:121)
  at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:333)
  at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(HttpsURLConnection.java:291)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:85)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:62)
  at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:1018)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.EndpointAddress.openConnection(EndpointAddress.java:202)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.createHttpConnection(HttpClientTransport.java:202)
  at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:102)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: pkcs12
 not found
  at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:616)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.getDefaultKeyManager(SSLContextImpl.java:603)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:495)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
  at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1238)
  ... 24 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: pkcs12
 KeyStore not available
  at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
  at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)
  at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:613)
  ... 33 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Good ol' Netbeans, telling me my build is successful...

In case someone still wants the code after all that:

```
package stsclientexample3;

import java.net.URL;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.Dispatch;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature;

import org.oasis_open.docs.ws_sx.ws_trust._200512.RequestSecurityTokenType;

public class STSClientExample3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
    final Service service 
      = Service.create( 
              new URL("file://\\project\\VendorDemo\\DocumentAPIv22Methods\\EchoSignDocumentService22Demo\\Java\\STSClientExample2\\web\\WEB-INF\\wsdl\\SecurityTokenService.wsdl"),
                        new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", "SecurityTokenService") 
                       );
    Iterator<QName> ports = service.getPorts();
    while (ports.hasNext()) {
        QName port = ports.next();
        System.out.println(port.toString());
    }

    final Dispatch dispatch 
      = service.createDispatch(new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/securitytokenservice", "CustomBinding_IWSTrust13Sync"), 
                                JAXBContext.newInstance("org.oasis_open.docs.ws_sx.ws_trust._200512"), 
                                Mode.PAYLOAD, 
                                new AddressingFeature()
                              );

    final BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) dispatch;

    final Map requestContext = provider.getRequestContext();

    requestContext.put(BindingProvider.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue");

    final RequestSecurityTokenType request = new RequestSecurityTokenType();

    dispatch.invoke(new JAXBElement<RequestSecurityTokenType>
                          (new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512", "RequestSecurityToken"), 
                            RequestSecurityTokenType.class, 
                            request)
                          );
        }
         catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println("all done");
    }

    public static void disableCertificates()
    {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = 
            {new X509TrustManager() 
                {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() { return null; }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
                }
            };
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            HostnameVerifier hv 
                    = new HostnameVerifier() { public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) { return true; } };
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        } 
        catch (Exception localException) 
        {
            System.out.println("Problem disabling SSL certificates: " + localException.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I notice there is a spurious linebreak when it prints 'pkcs12' in the exception message. If those `-D` options are set in a `.bat` file make sure there is not any **invisible character** following the `...Type=pkcs12` such as an extra CR, a lone LF, a tab, or similar. If in doubt, delete that line and the next one and *retype* them (not cut&paste) and maybe add a token like `...Type=pkcs12{space}-Dsacrifice=goat`.

Comment: Good thought, but these command line options are in the textfield box in NetBeans, and I've learned not to put extra linefeeds there.

Comment: It does look like it's getting messed up *somehow*. Can you try calling `System.setProperty` at the beginning of your `main`instead of the command-line option (or just in addition, since it will override the prior value)?

Answer (score 7):

I got a dumb mistake which caused the `NoSuchAlgorithm` exception.

If You (or anyone reading this post) is getting this error with `SpringBoot`, check Your `application.properties` and make sure that You **didn't** write the keystore type value like this:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type="PKCS12"
```

Note the **quotation marks** which **shouldn't be there**!

After removing them, the exception was gone.\

I am using Java 1.8:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

**P.S.** I know this is not that much connected to the question, but a Google query of the `NoSuchAlgorithm` exception led me to this page, so I thought it would be a good place to write this advice.

Comment: Thank you! But I should mention to others who find this, I got mine working **with** quotation marks (I also have a .yml file).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure next line is set to "true" in a file `YOUR_JDK/jre/lib/security/java.security`:

```
#
# Controls compatibility mode for the JKS keystore type.
#
# When set to 'true', the JKS keystore type supports loading
# keystore files in either JKS or PKCS12 format. When set to 'false'
# it supports loading only JKS keystore files.
#
keystore.type.compat=true
```

Comment: This seems to be a java 8 option; is there no equivalent for java 7?